# Multivariate Times Series Classification using Machine Learning Algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, classification, multivariate-time-series

I am fairly new to machine learning and am currently working on a way to classify time series data. In order to do so, I would like to get a better understanding of how time series data can be fed into machine learning algorithms.

Further information:

- Each sample is a time series consisting of 2000 time points. For each time point, there are several variables, like temperature, speed, acceleration, etc. The data can be represented like this:
  [data structure for one time series sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxCPO.png)
- The whole dataset consists of 3000 samples. 3000 samples x 2000 data points per sample = 6000000 data points for each variable.
- the goal is to classify the samples into classes from 0 to 4.

My first attempt was just feeding the data as an array into the machine learning algorithms.
Let's say, we just focus on temperature. We can now structure the data like this:
[input training data for a ml-algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT40S.png)
. Let X be the training input and y be the training output, the data looks like:

[21,21,22,...]=0

[35,35,35,...]=2

[11,12,12,...]=1

[18,17,18,...]=0

Can I just feed the machine learning algorithm (like SVCs) with array-type time series data like this? How does the algorithm know that the elements in the array are chronological data and not single features?

Here is an example code of what I did so far:

```
dataframe.head()

     'sample_nr' 'timestamp' 'temperature' 'speed' 'acceleration'
 0   1           0.01        21             -0.43   0.34205 
 1   1           0.02        21             -0.43   0.34205 
 2   1           0.03        22             -0.43   0.34205
```

Create a data_list, which contains all the sample_nr's in a list. Also, the dataframe gets grouped by the sample_nr

```
data_list = []
for sample_nr, sample_df in dataframe.groupby('sample_nr'):    
    dataframe.groupby('sample_nr'):
    data_list.append(dataframe)
```

For a first step, we will only focus on one feature, let's say the temperature:

```
X_list = []
y_list = []

for sample in data_list:
    temp_X = np.array(sample['temperature'])
    temp_y = sample['label'].unique()[0]

    X_list.append(temp_X)
    y_list.append(temp_y)
```

Transform the lists to pandas.Dataframes:

```
X_df = pd.DataFrame(X_list)
y_df = pd.DataFrame(y_list)
```

Now, the X_df is a 3000x2000 list: Each row describes a sample, and the values in the columns are the temperature values for each of the 2000 time steps:

```
print(X_df)
```

....**0**....**1**....**2**....**3**

**0** 21 21 22 22

**1** 35 35 35 36

**2** 11 12 12 12

Also, for the output value:

```
print(y_df)
```

....**0**

**0** 0

**1** 2

**2** 1

Now split up the dataframe to train and test data:

```
X_train_array, X_test_array, y_train_array, y_test_array = train_test_split(X_df, y_df, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
X_train_df = pd.DataFrame(X_train_array)
X_test_df = pd.DataFrame(X_test_array)
y_train_df = pd.DataFrame(y_train_array)
y_test_df = pd.DataFrame(y_test_array)

from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X_train_df, y_train_df)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far and is there any code to review where you are stuck ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I updated my question post with some code. The SVC model works like that, but I am unsure how to add more features to the model other than just temperature values